# Ubuntu 16.04 Intel graphic drivers fail in multiple applications

Tags: drivers, 16.04, google-chrome, intel-graphics, gpu

I am having graphical problems with my laptop and have consistently had it since I bought it. So far I have found no solution to my problems.

First my specs via lshw

```
laptop-aspire-e5-574      
description: Computer
width: 64 bits
capabilities: vsyscall32
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   physical id: 0
 *-memory
      description: System memory
      physical id: 0
      size: 15GiB
 *-cpu
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 1
      bus info: cpu@0
      size: 2676MHz
      capacity: 2700MHz
      width: 64 bits

      *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 07
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
         resources: irq:127 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

My errors are with Chrome, Chromium, Atom and VLC. The errors seems to be triggered by the intel graphics card, due to some yet unknown bug.

It is difficult to explain exactly what is happening, but in short.

- Applications like Chrome/Chromium, Atom and VLC cannot be opened after an unspecified amount of time of normal usage (browsing in FF mainly).
- I use Firefox as my primary browser. After aproximately 10 min or maybe 1h the other applications wont open on my laptop and crash.
- If I reboot and I open the said applications, they work just fine, and can even run for several hours, and I can subsequently open FF. If they run in parallel they seem to work.
- My best description of the problem is that when I use FF for a undetermined amount of time, the other applications wont open or run. If I reboot, everything goes back to normal and I can open the applications again. It is as if something at some point triggers within the software that crashes the other applications when I try to start them. I suspect it is starting to view Youtube on FF, that prevents the other applications from starting.
- There might be other applications that are affected and wont start, but I havent found other yet.

My error logs for the applications in question:

Chrome:

```
    laptop@laptop-Aspire-E5-574:~$ google-chrome
[5625:5625:1211/115914:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(14890)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[5625:5625:1211/115914:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4102)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[5625:5625:1211/115914:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(224)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[5625:5625:1211/115914:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(224)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[5692:5692:1211/115924:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(14890)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[5692:5692:1211/115924:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4102)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[5692:5692:1211/115924:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(224)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[5692:5692:1211/115924:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(224)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[5721:5721:1211/115934:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(14890)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[5721:5721:1211/115934:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4102)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[5721:5721:1211/115934:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(224)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[5721:5721:1211/115934:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(224)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[5736:5736:1211/120029:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(14890)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[5736:5736:1211/120029:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4102)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[5736:5736:1211/120029:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(224)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[5736:5736:1211/120029:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(224)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[5795:5795:1211/120035:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(14890)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[5795:5795:1211/120035:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4102)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[5795:5795:1211/120035:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(224)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[5795:5795:1211/120035:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(224)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 google-chrome
```

ATOM:

```
    laptop@laptop-Aspire-E5-574:~$ vlc
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[00000000014da148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00000000015ed4d8] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
[00000000015ed4d8] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
[00000000015ed4d8] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
[00000000015ed4d8] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.2
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[00007f681cc4d688] avcodec decoder: Using OpenGL/VAAPI/libswscale backend for VDPAU for hardware decoding.
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 24 and type 'Read', disabling...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Chromium + late error response for ATOM

```
    laptop@laptop-Aspire-E5-574:~$ atom
laptop@laptop-Aspire-E5-574:~$ chromium-browser/usr/bin/atom: line 119:  6209 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
Failed to get crash dump id.
Report Id: 
laptop@laptop-Aspire-E5-574:~$ vlc --avcodec-hw=vaapi
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[00000000019ef148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0000000001b02468] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
[0000000001b02468] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
[0000000001b02468] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
[0000000001b02468] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.2
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[00007f0bfd102618] avcodec decoder: Using Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Skylake - 1.7.1 for hardware decoding.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.2
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 24 and type 'Read', disabling...
[3]+  Killed                  google-chrome
```

Chromium with --verbose argument for more error logging.

```
        [7811:7811:1211/124931:VERBOSE1:cross_device_promo.cc(169)] CrossDevicePromo::MaybeBrowsingSessionStarted. Same browsing session as the last call.
[7811:7811:1211/124931:VERBOSE1:cross_device_promo.cc(169)] CrossDevicePromo::MaybeBrowsingSessionStarted. Same browsing session as the last call.
[7996:7996:1211/124931:VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(70)] Activated seccomp-bpf sandbox for process type: gpu-process.
[7996:7996:1211/124931:VERBOSE1:child_thread_impl.cc(371)] Mojo is disabled on child
[7996:7996:1211/124931:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3166)] GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[7996:7996:1211/124937:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(13835)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[7996:7996:1211/124937:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4021)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[7996:7996:1211/124937:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[7996:7996:1211/124937:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[7996:7996:1211/124937:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124937:VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(70)] Activated seccomp-bpf sandbox for process type: gpu-process.
[8006:8006:1211/124937:VERBOSE1:child_thread_impl.cc(371)] Mojo is disabled on child
[8006:8006:1211/124937:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3166)] GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[8006:8006:1211/124947:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(13835)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[8006:8006:1211/124947:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4021)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[8006:8006:1211/124947:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[8006:8006:1211/124947:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8006:8006:1211/124947:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124947:VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(70)] Activated seccomp-bpf sandbox for process type: gpu-process.
[8015:8015:1211/124947:VERBOSE1:child_thread_impl.cc(371)] Mojo is disabled on child
[8015:8015:1211/124947:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3166)] GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[7811:7840:1211/124949:VERBOSE1:mime_type_resource_handler.cc(294)] To buffer: https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/antiadblockfilters.txt?addonName=adblockpluschrome&addonVersion=1.12.4&application=chromium&applicationVersion=53.0.2785.143&platform=chromium&platformVersion=53.0.2785.143&lastVersion=201610291740&downloadCount=4%2B
[7811:7840:1211/124949:VERBOSE1:web_request_time_tracker.cc(181)] WR percent 82: https://notification.adblockplus.org/notification.json?addonName=adblockpluschrome&addonVersion=1.12.4&application=chromium&applicationVersion=53.0.2785.143&platform=chromium&platformVersion=53.0.2785.143&lastVersion=201611051451&downloadCount=4%2B: 15/894 = 0.0167942
[7811:7840:1211/124949:VERBOSE1:web_request_time_tracker.cc(181)] WR percent 80: https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/antiadblockfilters.txt?addonName=adblockpluschrome&addonVersion=1.12.4&application=chromium&applicationVersion=53.0.2785.143&platform=chromium&platformVersion=53.0.2785.143&lastVersion=201610291740&downloadCount=4%2B: 11/898 = 0.0123539
[7811:7840:1211/124949:VERBOSE1:mime_type_resource_handler.cc(294)] To buffer: https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/exceptionrules.txt?addonName=adblockpluschrome&addonVersion=1.12.4&application=chromium&applicationVersion=53.0.2785.143&platform=chromium&platformVersion=53.0.2785.143&lastVersion=201611051441&downloadCount=4%2B
[7811:7840:1211/124950:VERBOSE1:mime_type_resource_handler.cc(294)] To buffer: https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt?addonName=adblockpluschrome&addonVersion=1.12.4&application=chromium&applicationVersion=53.0.2785.143&platform=chromium&platformVersion=53.0.2785.143&lastVersion=201610291740&downloadCount=3
[7811:7840:1211/124950:VERBOSE1:web_request_time_tracker.cc(181)] WR percent 81: https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt?addonName=adblockpluschrome&addonVersion=1.12.4&application=chromium&applicationVersion=53.0.2785.143&platform=chromium&platformVersion=53.0.2785.143&lastVersion=201610291740&downloadCount=3: 14/1804 = 0.00803758
[7811:7840:1211/124951:VERBOSE1:web_request_time_tracker.cc(181)] WR percent 79: https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/exceptionrules.txt?addonName=adblockpluschrome&addonVersion=1.12.4&application=chromium&applicationVersion=53.0.2785.143&platform=chromium&platformVersion=53.0.2785.143&lastVersion=201611051441&downloadCount=4%2B: 6/2616 = 0.00257044
[8015:8015:1211/124957:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(13835)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[8015:8015:1211/124957:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4021)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[8015:8015:1211/124957:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[8015:8015:1211/124957:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8015:8015:1211/124957:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(57)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[8027:8027:1211/124957:VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(70)] Activated seccomp-bpf sandbox for process type: gpu-process.
[8027:8027:1211/124957:VERBOSE1:child_thread_impl.cc(371)] Mojo is disabled on child
[8027:8027:1211/124957:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3166)] GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil supported.
```

This has persisted for months now. I have no idea what to do and I am not sure if I can do anything. Is it possible that the problem is simply lack of support for this particular laptop make from intel graphics on Ubuntu?

And, Firefox runs very laggy in general. When scrolling I have lag. Surprisingly if I start Chrome (when I can do so) it stops lagging as long as the Crome browser runs in the background (passively).

Any suggestion would be very welcomed.

Comment: This may be not much of a help, but I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on HP ProBook 450 G3 with the same Intel i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz, and Intel HD 520 graphics, and I am not experiencing any of the problems you are having. May be the fault is not with the Intel graphics?

Comment: But your make is not Acer Aspire. Maybe my problems are specifically due to the build and hardware specs?

Comment: It very well may be. May be someone will have a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the answer myself. A couple of google searches finally put me on the right path.

1) I ended up here: https://plus.google.com/+JonMasters/posts/BqWLEjenLKv which confirms there is an Intel Skylake problem with Chromium/Chrome at least.

2) This further let to that solving the issue could be done by installing a kernel update, as I was not even aware of that Ubuntu is not up to date with at least stable kernel versions.

In order to check your current kernel version run the following:

```
uname -a
uname -r
```

This will show the kernel version. To install the latest stable kernel for Ubuntu 16.04 go here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-linux-kernel-4-6-ubuntu-16-04/

3) I additionally found what is a similar problem many seem to have with their linux graphics card here: https://github.com/linuxenko/ubuntu-skylake-i915-video-fix

In order to know what graphic card you have run all or either of the following commands

```
 glxinfo|grep vendor
 glxinfo|grep renderer
 sudo lspci|grep VGA
```

At this point the solution is to run different kernels and try out solutions for the Skylake graphic card. Not sure if it all works perfect yet, but the above resources should put anyone that had this problem and did not know where to start on the right path.